# BDD Gherkin Selenium Java - Error Trouble shooting

Tags: java, maven, selenium, bdd, gherkin

```
    package cucumberselelniumgherkin;


    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    import cucumber.api.java.After;
    import cucumber.api.java.Before;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

    public class test {


        public WebDriver driver;

         @Before
            public void setup() {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        @Given("^I open google$")
        public void I_open_google() {
            //Set implicit wait of 10 seconds and launch google
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        }

        @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
        public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String additionTerms) {
            //Write term in google textbox
            WebElement googleTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
            googleTextBox.sendKeys(additionTerms);

            //Click on searchButton
            WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
            searchButton.click();
        }

        @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
        public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
            //Get result from calculator
            WebElement calculatorTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("cwos"));
            String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();

            //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4
            Assert.assertEquals(result, expectedResult);

            driver.close();
        }

         @After
          public void closeBrowser() {
          driver.quit();
         }

    }
```

When I am trying to run it as maven test getting the below mentioned    error, please help this is my first attempt in getting into BDD    stuff, whats wrong in the code. Please suggest what can i do to fix this its been bothering my mind so much !

```
        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bddSel 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 1.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/maven-metadata.xml (4 KB at 6.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.5/cucumber-junit-1.2.5.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.5/cucumber-junit-1.2.5.pom (3 KB at 5.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.5/cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.5/cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar (22 KB at 27.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ bddSel ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\workspace\bddSel\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ bddSel ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to E:\workspace\bddSel\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.22\cssparser-0.9.22.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.26\htmlunit-2.26.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[6,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[12,25] package cucumber.api.java does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[13,25] package cucumber.api.java does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[14,28] package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[15,28] package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[16,28] package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[23,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[28,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Given
  location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[35,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class When
  location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[46,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Then
  location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[58,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class After
  location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[53,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Assert
  location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[INFO] 15 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.233 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-05T09:45:37+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project bddSel: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.22\cssparser-0.9.22.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.26\htmlunit-2.26.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[6,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[12,25] package cucumber.api.java does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[13,25] package cucumber.api.java does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[14,28] package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[15,28] package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[16,28] package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[23,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Before
[ERROR] location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[28,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Given
[ERROR] location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[35,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class When
[ERROR] location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[46,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Then
[ERROR] location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[58,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class After
[ERROR] location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] /E:/workspace/bddSel/src/main/java/cucumberselelniumgherkin/test.java:[53,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Assert
[ERROR] location: class cucumberselelniumgherkin.test
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Below is the POM from the project - Thank you so much for your reply. I am so stuck :( help please. I have tried almost everything cant seem to figure it out. I am new to Selenium and bdd so trying to learn. So grateful for your response.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CucumberJavaProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>bddSel</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  
</project>
```

Comment: could you paste the maven dependency section here as well

Comment: added bro thank you so much help, much appreicated

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me out with this query as well. Let me know incase there is a need of more information on this.

Comment: Can someone look into this.

Comment: Guys can anyone help with this Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same version for cucumber-junit and cucumber-java (1.2.5). The version 1.1.2 is from 30-Jan-2013.

Update:
Your `test.java` class is located at `src/main/java`. However your dependencies are set to scope `test`. This means they are only used for test compilation and execution. So when your maven project tries to compile the `test.java` class it did not have the needed classes in the classpath.

So move your `test.java` class into the `src/test/java` folder and try again.
You can also check my example project which shows the minimal setup to use most BDD frameworks to check where which file or class is located:
https://github.com/mszalbach/BDD/tree/master/cucumber

Comment: I did getting the above updated the error in the thread above.

Comment: I tested this with your classes and an example cucumber project. It could compile the only thing missing was setting the path to the geckodriver to be able to start firefox. So maybe more a problem like the corrupted cache like stated in the other answer. But never less use the same version for both dependencies, because they are related.

Comment: I re-did the complete thing after deleting all the files from the repo and also tried re-creating the maven project but still didnt work ...Can you suggest where i could may be read on set up may be i am missing something not sure :(

Comment: Check my update after checking your output again I noticed a problem with the dependency scope and where your java class is located.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it's works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberBasic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like some jar file is corrupted. This is not the best solution but might work from you. Please delete all the files under following folder and re-download them using maven.

For windows

```
C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository folder
```

for linux

```
/home/egnyte/.m2/repository
```

To download again you can right click on your project on your favourtie IDE and there you can find the option. you you can use command line and run

```
mvn clean test
```

Comment: @AvinashPandey so you deleted everything from  `C:\Users\Avinash\.m2\repository\` and still getting error ?

Comment: may be it taking the same jars from local repo. after deleting everything can your run following command. `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean test`

Comment: I did try this did not work either, now i am trying by making a new project of maven would get back here in-case i get stuck. However it would be great you could suggest a tutorial i could follow for setting this up.